# Ayuda con una consulta

Tags: mysql

soy principiante, tengo las siguientes tablas

personal
 - id_empleado
 - nombre_empleado
 - horario
 - 
horarios
 - nombre_horario
 - hora_inicial
 - hora_final

quiero hacer una consulta del id del empleado donde pueda unir la tabla horarios, el nombre horario es igual al campo horario

gracias he buscado pero solo me da error

Esta es la consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT personal.nombre_completo_, personal.nombre_horario FROM personal INNER JOIN horarios ON personal.horario_ = horarios.nombre_horario";
```

Comment: Aunque te de error, pon lo que has intentado, así te explicamos los errores, corregimos el código y vas aprendiendo. Pulsa en [edit]  para mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT personal.nombre_completo_, personal.nombre_horario FROM personal INNER JOIN horarios ON personal.horario_ = horarios.nombre_horario";

Comment: Creo que seria bueno agregar como tienes tus tablas para poder ayudarte, a simple vista puedo decir que tu join de personal deberías compararlo al horarios id, no al nombre, pero depende mucho como tengas tu tablas.

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo para tus que tus tablas pueden relacionarse:

```
Personal[id_empleado, nombre_empleado,id_horario]

Horarios[id,nombre_horario, hora_inicial, hora_final]
```

La consulta seria algo asi

```sql
SELECT * FROM personal p
INNER JOIN horarios h ON h.id = p.id_horario
```

Answer (score 0):

No te preocupes, lo importante es que lo intentes y te des cuenta de esos errores. Lo que sucede es que no está enlazando las tablas para que luego pueda buscarlo con una consulta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta que requieres, si es que entiendo bien, sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT P.id_empleado AS ID_EMPLEADO,
   P.nombre_empleado AS NOMBRE
FROM personal as P
INNER JOIN horarios as H
ON H.id_horario = P.id_horario
WHERE H.nombre_horario = 'Horario 1'; -- Aquí pones el nombre del horario
```

La clausula "**INNER JOIN**" sirve para unir tablas de forma interna, el "**ON**" nos permite especificar con qué campos vamos a enlazar las tablas, en este caso, lo enlazamos por el campo en común que tienen "**id_horario**".

El resultado sería algo como:

[image: resultSet-horario]

Comment: Super amigo, gracias te agradezco saludos

Comment: De nada amigo, saludos :D